# Theming html output of privatemsg 6.x-2.x module

Tags: theming, privatemsg

How can I theme the output of [Privatemsg](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg)? I took look at http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.theme.inc/group/theming/1, but I didn't understood how to use that.
I want to totally change the HTML output for the message list.

How do I use my custom date format in the messages? I guess the `format_date()` function would help me, but how do I use it correctly?

`print format_date($messages_timestamp, 'custom', 'd=m=Y')` returns "01.01.1970." What is that?

Comment: Which of these theme function are you looking at ? Does `$messages_timestamp` displays a timestamp ?

Comment: Please specify what exactly you want to do. The generic answer to your generic question is "use theme overrides". And the format_date() question is completely unrelated to this so I suggest you make that a separate question. Note that Privatemsg for Drupal 7 allows you to configure the used date format, but that feature will probably not be backported to 6.x-2.x as it depends on a new core feature.

Comment: It seems strange that you get "01.01.1970" when the format passed to the function is "d=m=Y;" I would expect the result to eventually be "01=01=1970."

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is some information.

- That list shows *threads*, not single messages. You can't change that, at least not with theming. The only thing you easily can do is enable the privatemsg_limits module and set the number of messages per thread to 1. That basically disables threading and each message will be sent as a new thread. Then they will be shown separetly on the list, but they will also be shown separately on the thread view page. [Privatemsg views](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg_views) is currently only compatible with 6.x-1.x and looks rather unmaintained at this point.
- You can configure the displayed columns and their order in the Privatemsg settings.
- The theming functions are used to customize the content of single columns. For example, to show a different date format, you can override [phptemplate_privatemsg_list_field__last_updated()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.theme.inc/function/phptemplate_privatemsg_list_field__last_updated/6-2):

  ```
  function phptemplate_privatemsg_list_field__thread_started($thread) {
    $field = array();
    $field['data'] = format_date($thread['thread_started'], 'custom', 'd.m.Y H:i');
    $field['class'] = 'privatemsg-list-date-started';
    return $field;
  }
  ```

  In 7.x, Privatemsg shows a different date format depending on the age of the message, that is done in [privatemsg_format_date()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.module/function/privatemsg_format_date/7-1) if you want to backport that.
- To change how the table *looks*, you should be able to that with just CSS. Privatemsg adds tons of classes to that table, including a seperate class for every column and classes for rows with new messages and soon for [unreplied messages too](http://drupal.org/node/147420).

Comment: What if i want to make message list (Not inside thread) tabeless?

Comment: I want to make message list without a table headers and table at all. Gonna use DIV's instead of table

Comment: You can either override http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.theme.inc/function/theme_privatemsg_list/6-2 or use the API directly as outlined in http://drupal.org/node/624528. It will however require quite a bit of code to make the table a list or something. I'm not sure why you'd want to do that. Even the messages list on facebok is a table, it's just the CSS that makes it look nice.

Comment: And how to display only 1st author of the message not all recipients.

Comment: well, do u know a social networking site - vk.com my chief wants my messages list tabeless, without table header and content profile field_photo.

Comment: @Berdir: u gave me a link to API http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.theme.inc/function/theme_privatemsg_list/6-2

But i don't know how to use it correctly... put me on the right way please! I want to create one more column for profile picture and merge last updated date and participants.

Answer (score 0):

[format_date()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/format_date/7) requires a UNIX timestamp, which is an integer containing the number of seconds passed from January 1, 1970; when you pass a value that is 0, `NULL`, or a string that doesn't start with a number, then the result of the function is January 1, 1970.

In your case, it could also be that `$messages_timestamp` is not a defined variable, a variable that has been unset, or a variable that has been set to `NULL`.

Comment: Sorry for being not exactly. Berdir, i've already asked you on drupal.org about theming and you gave me a link on your API. I don't know how to use those theme functions to change the html output of **messages-list**. Can you throw me an examples?

Comment: @Heihachi: Again, provide an example of *what exactly* you want to change and I can probably give you the code you need for that. Making up a random example won't help you much I think.

Comment: @Berdir: I want to theme - when you press on link My Messages. Attaching screenshot - http://pics.kz/s1/ae/e3/dd/aee3dde7d4037de9d79f3f5c0c52708f.jpg
It's a my messages page.

Comment: @Berdir: also as you can see in the data column it displays only d.m.Y without a time. In a clean drupal install i had no problems with displaying time near d.m.Y.

Comment: @Heihachi: Yes, I know that already. What there? Do you want to change the content of a single column, the order of comments, look and feel of the whole table...?

Comment: @Berdir: sorry, didn't understood correctly. I want to theme look and feel of the whole table.

Comment: @Berdir: What is the module privatemsg views? With this addon i can  change the way of threads/mailbox displaying?

Comment: For example, if i want to display only incoming messages (messages from user, without my answers) separately and outcoming either? I mean displaying only incoming messages in inbox without your answers and in sent messages - display only your answers to a user. Here's screenshots:

My Messages Page: http://pics.kz/s5/08/43/fa/0843fabbfa4d000a2b817d7c5c0eddcf.jpg

When you press on message:
http://pics.kz/s4/e4/c8/1b/e4c81b575a4758eb8befe9296c5c687c.jpg

same with sent messages